# How to create single pulse animation effect in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I would like to scale some view with animation and go back to the original scale. The way I figured out to do it is by using `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` with deadline matching the end of scale up animation. As shown in following code. My question is if there is better way to do that (more SwiftUI way, or just simpler).

```
import SwiftUI

struct ExampleView: View {
    @State private var isPulse = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello")
                .scaleEffect(isPulse ? 3 : 1)
            ZStack {
                Capsule()
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 40)
                    .foregroundColor(.pink)
                Text("Press me")
            }
            .onTapGesture {
                let animationDuration = 0.4
                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: animationDuration)) {
                    isPulse.toggle()
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + animationDuration) {
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                        isPulse.toggle()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ExampleView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ExampleView()
    }
}
```

[Pulse animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kNu2.gif)

Comment: Anyway if using `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` with deadline matching expected end of animation is good solution I have no problem with it. From my experience (while testing) it works fine.

Comment: Following, since this is a problem that doesn’t seem well-solved by the library. For what it’s worth, I end up doing the solution you have come up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two `withAnimation` statements with the second one that scales the text down using a `.delay(animationDuration)`:

```
.onTapGesture {
    let animationDuration = 0.4
    withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: animationDuration)) {
        isPulse.toggle()
    }
    withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: animationDuration).delay(animationDuration)) {
        isPulse.toggle()
    }
}
```

You could also replace the two calls to `withAnimation` with a `for loop`:

```
.onTapGesture {
    let animationDuration = 0.4
    for delay in [0, animationDuration] {
        withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: animationDuration).delay(delay)) {
            isPulse.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```